# KDE4: Share Nepomuk data

Tags: kde-4, nepomuk

is it possible to share the nepomuk data? I have several users here and the users should be able to read and modify the tags and comments for each file with public access. Also it should be possible to tag and comment the files in each private home-directory.

Is this possible with the current KDE 4.3.2?

Thanks for your help
Frank

Answer (score 0):

In this thread

http://trueg.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/nepomuk-data-layout/#comment-736

I asked the question above. This feature is planned for KDE 4.5. It'll take a while :-(